# How do I Load the file name into a new column through SSIS, using variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

I have a set of files that are dynamically changing, I am using the foreach loop container to update them.

I am using two variables (1) for file path and (2) for source folder.

I need to insert the file names into a separate column.

File names:

```
XYZ0000_2016_04_Application_Report.csv
ABC0000.10_2016_04_Application_Report.csv
```

I need to insert only `XYZ0000` into a new column.

How do I do it with the help of variables?

Comment: And the second file: ABC0000.10 or ABC0000?

Comment: ***I need to update the file names into a separate column.*** What does it mean literally?

Comment: I have multiple files like **XYZ0000_2016_04_Application_Report.csv**, I need only the part of the file **XYZ0000** and i need put **XYZ0000** into a new column.  How do i do it using variables?

Comment: @Joe it is just an example **ABC0000.10** this is how a file is.

Comment: Yes, but in the name of file, your separator is _?

Comment: @Joe:  that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Derived Column` transformation to your data flow and use the following expression:

`LEFT(@[User::FileName],FINDSTRING("_", @[User::FileName], 1))`

*This assumes you are recording your file name from the Loop container*

Comment: @Dave:  thank you for the help and that query helped me. can you please help me out with another one:- I have the file path as **D:\SGIP\test1\XYZ0000_2016_04_Application_Report** how do I do this for this file path.

Comment: @mirsafi Are you not saving just the filename in a variable?  If you are the answer I have given will work in that situation as well.

Answer (score 1):

So, try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(yourfield, 0, CHARINDEX('_', yourfield))
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help joe.  But i need to do it in the SSIS package.

Comment: How do i Load the file name into the a column through SSIS, using variables?